# Free particle encountering an infinite potential barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering, reflection, quantum-tunneling

I understand that a wave function cannot penetrate through a barrier that has infinite potential. However when the wave function reflects off from the barrier what does this look like? If we're in a well, does this create a standing wave? or If its just a barrier, does the wave function just move of and move in the opposite direction?

Comment: It's simply the classical optics of a perfect mirror, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

If your wave is going toward an infinite wall it cannot penetrate it, therefore the wave will be completely reflected (since there is no probability to pass through the potential). For instance, if you have a wave (with an infinite wall in $x=0$) of the form,

$\psi(x) = Ae^{ikx}$ the reflected wave will be $\psi(x) = -Ae^{-ikx}$

Comment: $\psi(x) = -A e^{-ikx}$, surely?  After all, the total wave (incident + reflected) has to be zero at $x = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I think we can write the total wave function as $A(e^{ikx} - e^{-ikx})$

Comment: Thanks for the note